# Xampp connects to MariaDB instead of mysql (KNP/SymfonyCasts tutorial "how to speak database")

Tags: mysql, localhost, mariadb

I am following tutorial from KNP/SymfonyCasts and I have problem with connecting to mysql.

That's what tutor write in her terminal
[image: tutor terminal]

And that is my output
[image]

I assume this matter so... How can I change this? They do not cover issue, just mention that if blank password doesn't work, I should use "root".

Comment: MariaDB is a MySQL-compatible server.

Comment: @tkausl So it basically doesn't matter that I got different output? I thought that it's about what is on the server side and if I follow exact steps I should get the same info. But ok, I always get stressed when my output is different from example one :P Thanks!

Comment: @Aerogirl Correct, it wont matter that your are on MariaDB and your instructor is on MySQL. They will work exactly the same

Comment: @JoeBurton Many thanks, then!

Comment: Are they both installed?  On different ports (`-P`)?

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB comes with XAMPP. 
Since you installed XAMPP and are using it, obviously it will connect to its MariaDB installation. MariaDB is Mysql.

Don't install the MySQL that comes bundled with XAMPP or just change the config and point it to your other MySQL installation if you have one (a community server, for example)

Or just use the MariaDB(Mysql) from XAMPP.